# Visual Studio 2010 setup project - Uninstall

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project

I have an Outlook Add-In setup. The first user installed it using the "Just me" option. Another user logged in on the same machine and installed the same Add-In using the "Just me" option. When the second user uninstalls the Add-In, the files in the "Program Files" directory will be deleted and the first user will not be able to use the Add-In.

Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an article which may help: http://setupanddeployment.com/installation-environment/peruser-permachine/

Basically, per-user installation should use per-user locations and per-machine installations should use per-machine locations. Program Files is a per-machine location, so it shouldn't be used by a per-user installation.

Either you make your installer per-machine (no per-user option) or you change the installation path dynamically based on the selected installation type (per-user or per-machine).

Comment: After reading this article I noticed that I can’t rely on per user installations for my Add-In because they may not be power users or administrators and my Add-In deploys assemblies in the GAC. So I need to do a per machine installation. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, GAC deployment requires Administrator privileges.